# How to spool the result of this pl/SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

So that is my code and i have a cursor and i want to spool the result of this cursor taht you can see in the dbms_output.

```
set serveroutput on
clear screen;

spool C:\Users\p.k\Documents\text.txt

declare
    l_output   utl_file.file_type;
    cursor cp_username (p_v_username in varchar2)
    is
       select owner, table_name          
       from   all_tables
       where owner = p_v_username
       order by owner, table_name ;   
begin
     l_output := utl_file.fopen();
     dbms_output.put_line('Alle Tabellen der User: &g_username');
     for cp_kur in cp_username('&g_username') loop
         dbms_output.put_line('Tabelle: '|| cp_kur.table_name );
     end loop;
end;

spool off;
```

i have started using the spool first of all but he has create the file and has putted the output with the error and then i started using the utl_file looking  at a tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `utl_file.put` as follows:

```
declare
    l_output   utl_file.file_type; 
begin
     l_output := utl_file.fopen(
                  'utl_dir' -- File location
                , 'test_file.txt' -- File name
                , 'w' -- Open mode: w = write.
                    );
     utl_file.put(l_output,'Alle Tabellen der User: &g_username');
     for cp_kur in (select owner, table_name          
       from   all_tables
       where owner = '&g_username'
       order by owner, table_name) loop
         utl_file.put(l_output, 'Tabelle: '|| cp_kur.table_name );
     end loop;
     utl_file.fclose(l_output);
end;
```

Comment: i have use your version but i have some erros like : i have to declare the id  'FHANDLE' and thats there too much things in the variable  l_outpout
 i dont know if it work with you

Comment: i have use your version but i have one errors left : thats there too much things in the variable  l_outpout
 i dont know if it work with you

Comment: Thanks i try it and have a pb again but because my server has the operating system Linux and there is no 'C:\Users\p.k\Documents' i have only access locally on my PC.

Comment: But i have a question it'is not possible for me to just use the spool?

Comment: `utl_file` can write in the file on DB server only. If you want to create the file in your local system (DB client) then SPOOL is needed. you need to try SPOOL by yourself and if you find any difficulties then put it on SO.

Comment: i have already tried with the spool that's why i used the utl_file. i can show you on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850441/how-to-spool-the-result-of-this-pl-sql-procedure